# Directx11 Rendering with C++ Not Working

Tags: c++, geometry, rendering, directx-11

I started to practice rendering with directx11.I had done rendering in directx 9. But DX11 is a pain in the ass.. I couldn't manage to even draw a simple traingle. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I tried removing depth and stencil buffer but was in vain.
So after brooding over this issue for 2 hours i still can't find the solution.

Can anyone please be kind enough to help me.. Please guys

Thanks

Here is the full code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <D3D11.h>
#include <D3DX10math.h>
#include <dxerr.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#include "CoreApp.h"
#include "AppTime.h"


using namespace std;
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")




LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

bool InitWindowClass(HINSTANCE hinst,int shw,HWND * _hwnd,WNDCLASSEX * exClass);

RECT windowWidth = {0,0, 512,512};

void TW_CALL _Callbak(void * clenddata);

void InitPipeline();
void initGraphics();




ID3D11VertexShader * vshader = 0;
ID3D11PixelShader * pixelShader = 0;
ID3D11Device * d3dDevice = 0;   
ID3D11DeviceContext * d3dContext = 0;

#pragma region verticles
struct CVertex
{
    float X,Y,Z;
    D3DXCOLOR col;
};

namespace Color
{
    D3DXCOLOR white (255);
    D3DXCOLOR Red ((float)255,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
#pragma endregion


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst,HINSTANCE previnst,LPSTR cmdLine,int show)
{


    // Window Params
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSEX exClass;
    MSG msg;
    GameTime time;

    // Iniitaliztion
    SecureZeroMemory(&hwnd,sizeof(HWND));
    SecureZeroMemory(&exClass,sizeof(exClass));
    SecureZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));
    SecureZeroMemory(&time,sizeof(time));

if(InitWindowClass(inst,show,&hwnd,&exClass))
    {
    // Directx  11 Functionalities

        #pragma region Create the device


        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_LEVEL; // Output feature level



            HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(0,
                                           D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                           0,
                                           0,       // No flags 
                                           0,0,
                                           D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                           &d3dDevice,
                                           &feature_LEVEL,&d3dContext);
            if(FAILED(hr))
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd,L"Failed TO CREATE DEVICE",L"ERROR",0);
            }

      #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Multisampling
            UINT multisampleQuality = 0;
            d3dDevice->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,4,&multisampleQuality);


        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region DescribeSwapChain
            DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapDesc;

            // Allocate Mommory
             SecureZeroMemory(&swapDesc,sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

            swapDesc.BufferDesc.Width =  512;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 512;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator= 60;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
            swapDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

            //MSAA 
            swapDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
            swapDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = multisampleQuality -1;

            //BackBuffer
            swapDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
            swapDesc.BufferCount = 1;

            swapDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
            swapDesc.Windowed = true;

            swapDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
            swapDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;


        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region CreateSwapChain

            #pragma region Obtain DXGIFactory

        // DXGIFactory >> DXGIAdaptor >> DXGIDevice

            // Get the DXGI device
            IDXGIDevice * dxgiDevice = 0;
            d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice),(void**)&dxgiDevice);

            // Obtain DXGIAdaptor
            IDXGIAdapter * dxgiAdaptor = 0;
            dxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter),(void**)&dxgiAdaptor);

            IDXGIFactory * dxgiFactory = 0;
            dxgiAdaptor->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory),(void**)&dxgiFactory);
            #pragma endregion


            IDXGISwapChain * SwapChain = 0;
                if(FAILED(dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(d3dDevice,&swapDesc,&SwapChain)))
                {
                    MessageBox(hwnd,L"Failed Creating back buffer",L"Error",0);
                }



                dxgiFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(hwnd,0);


                //Release COMs
            dxgiAdaptor->Release();
            dxgiDevice->Release();
            dxgiFactory->Release();

            /*IDXGISwapChain * SwapChain = 0;
            if(FAILED(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(0,D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,0,0,0,0,D3D11_SDK_VERSION,&swapDesc,&SwapChain,&d3dDevice,&feature_LEVEL,&d3dContext)))
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd,L"Failed Creating back buffer and device",L"Error",0);
            }*/


        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Create Render Target View

            ID3D11RenderTargetView * RenderTarget ;
            ID3D11Texture2D * backBuffer ;

            SecureZeroMemory(&backBuffer,sizeof(ID3D11Texture2D));
            SecureZeroMemory(&RenderTarget,sizeof(ID3D11RenderTargetView));

            SwapChain->GetBuffer(0,__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),(void**)&backBuffer);
            d3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer,NULL,&RenderTarget);
        //  d3dContext->OM
            //Release COM
            backBuffer->Release();



        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Create Depth Stencil Texture

            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthDesc;

            SecureZeroMemory(&depthDesc,sizeof(depthDesc)); // Allocate Memeory

            depthDesc.ArraySize = 1;

            //Flags
            depthDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
            depthDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            depthDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT; // Format

            // Area
            depthDesc.Height = 512;
            depthDesc.Width = 512;

            // Mipmap and MXAA
            depthDesc.MipLevels= 1;
            depthDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
            depthDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = multisampleQuality -1;


            depthDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            depthDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

            // Create and initialize pointers
            ID3D11Texture2D * DepthTexture = 0;
            ID3D11DepthStencilView * depthView = 0;

            //d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthDesc,0,&DepthTexture);
        //  d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(DepthTexture,0,&depthView);


        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Bind to Output
            d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1,&RenderTarget,NULL); // removed depth buffer for testing but still wont work
        #pragma endregion

        #pragma region Create ViewPort
            D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;

            //Clear mommory
            SecureZeroMemory(&viewport,sizeof(viewport));

            viewport.Height = 512;
            viewport.Width = 512;
            viewport.MinDepth = 0;
            viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
            viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
            viewport.TopLeftY = 0;

            d3dContext->RSSetViewports(1,&viewport);
        #pragma endregion


            TwInit(ETwGraphAPI::TW_DIRECT3D11,d3dDevice);
            TwWindowSize(swapDesc.BufferDesc.Width,swapDesc.BufferDesc.Height);


            time.Reset();

            InitPipeline();
            #pragma region Vertex Buffer Creation
            CVertex vertex[3] = {
                {0,0,0,Color::white},
                {0.5,0,0,Color::white},
                {0.25,0.5,0,Color::Red},
            };

            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC VbufferDesc;
            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vBufferInit;

            SecureZeroMemory(&vertex,sizeof(vertex));
                SecureZeroMemory(&VbufferDesc,sizeof(VbufferDesc));
                SecureZeroMemory(&vBufferInit,sizeof(vBufferInit));

                VbufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
                VbufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
                VbufferDesc.ByteWidth = 3* sizeof(CVertex);
                VbufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_FLAG::D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
                VbufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
                VbufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;


                vBufferInit.pSysMem = vertex;

                ID3D11Buffer * Vbuffer = {0};

                    d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&VbufferDesc,&vBufferInit,&Vbuffer);



            #pragma endregion

            while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
        {
            if(PeekMessage(&msg,hwnd,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
          {
              TranslateMessage(&msg);
              DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }else{


             // Update Sequences

                // Rendering
                d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget,D3DXCOLOR(0,0,300,0));


                UINT stride = sizeof(CVertex);
                UINT offset = 0;    
                d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&Vbuffer,&stride,&offset);
                d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY::D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);
                d3dContext->Draw(3,0);


                SwapChain->Present(0,0);
            }
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;

}

void InitPipeline()
{
    ID3D10Blob * vBuffBlob = 0;
ID3D10Blob * pBuffBlob = 0;

    //SecureZeroMemory(&vBuffBlob,sizeof(ID3D10Blob));
    //SecureZeroMemory(&pBuffBlob,sizeof(ID3D10Blob));
    SecureZeroMemory(&vshader,sizeof(ID3D11VertexShader));
    SecureZeroMemory(&pixelShader,sizeof(ID3D11PixelShader));

    HRESULT hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"source.shader",0,0,"VShader","vs_4_0",0,0,0,&vBuffBlob,0,0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"source.shader",0,0,"PShader","ps_4_0",0,0,0,&pBuffBlob,0,0);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        MessageBeep(1);

    d3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(vBuffBlob->GetBufferPointer(),vBuffBlob->GetBufferSize(),NULL,&vshader);
    d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(pBuffBlob->GetBufferPointer(),pBuffBlob->GetBufferSize(),NULL,&pixelShader);


D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inp[] = {
    {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
    {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,0,12,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
};
    SecureZeroMemory(inp,sizeof(inp));

    ID3D11InputLayout * inputL = 0;
    d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(inp,2,vBuffBlob->GetBufferPointer(),vBuffBlob->GetBufferSize(),&inputL);


    d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(inputL);

                d3dContext->VSSetShader(vshader,NULL,0);
                d3dContext->PSSetShader(pixelShader,0,0);

    pBuffBlob->Release();
    vBuffBlob->Release();

}


// Initialize and show the Window
bool InitWindowClass(HINSTANCE hinst,int shw,HWND * _hwnd,WNDCLASSEX * exClass)
{

     exClass->cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
     exClass->hCursor = LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
     exClass->hInstance = hinst;
     exClass->lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
     exClass->lpszClassName = L"DX_Test";
     exClass->lpszMenuName = L"Test";
     exClass->hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
     RegisterClassEx(exClass);


     AdjustWindowRect(&windowWidth,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,false);

     (*_hwnd) = CreateWindowEx(0,L"DX_Test",L"Test",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,500,200,windowWidth.right -  windowWidth.left,windowWidth.bottom-windowWidth.top,NULL,NULL,hinst,0);

     ShowWindow((*_hwnd),shw);


     UpdateWindow(*_hwnd);

     return true;

}



// Message Loop
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wparam,LPARAM lparam)
{
   .....
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [Direct3D Tutorial Win32 Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef)? You might also find [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) helpful.

Comment: This is a 'debug my program' question which isn't great for SO.  First start by enabling the DEBUG device and look for ERRORS or WARNINGS. Second, make sure every function that returns an HRESULT is validated--for example, you aren't checking to see if CreateVertexShader or CreatePixelShader actually worked.

Comment: Hi thanks for all the help..But I did check if the Shader were created.But i didnt get any errors.  Please do help me solve this Thanks

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn  Thanks for the tutorials it is so much easier than the book by Frank D Luna which is terribly confusing and kinda complicated ..Thanks                                                  And the Directx Toolkit is really helpfull.But it doesnt let me learn basics of 3d design.It would be equivalent of using a 3d engine directly ..But I wanted to learn it so that i can have a good knowlede which may help me in get a good job                          T                           Thanks againn

Comment: With DirectX Tool Kit, you have all the source so you can just step into it to see what's happening. The point is that you can focus on learning parts of Direct3D 11 while relying on DXTK for others until you are ready to learn them. As for your code, it's not clear what's wrong from your code. A lot could go wrong, and debugging graphics code is not trivial. Follow along with the tutorial and then modify it as needed to get the output you want.

Comment: Thanks I will download and try out the Toolkit              Thanks for your time and effort for helping me I really appriciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're not properly initializing the `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` structure. You have:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inp[] = {
    {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,0,0},
    {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,0,12}
};
SecureZeroMemory(inp,sizeof(inp));
```

which partially initializes the structure then completely zeros it. That code snippet should be:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inp[] = {
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"COLOR",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
};
```

which gives the full description of the input and how it's laid out in memory.

Second, I'd suggest putting this entire project aside and spending about a week reading through both of the tutorials Chuck has linked, reading as much info on MSDN as possible, and give a good read through the book by Frank D. Luna. A lot of this stuff is addressed in his book, and all of the code is available online, so the book isn't required to learn the API (though it certainly helps).

DirectX 9 was easier to get used to, as the fixed function pipeline helped to organize a lot of this extra work. However, if you used DirectX 9.0c and Shader Model 2.x/3, a lot of this code is very similar, and is now required as there is no longer a fixed function pipeline in D3D.

Comment: Thanks For the help..But i actually have written it in my code.But i dont know how i missed it out here...  Thank you so much for the help.Sorry coldnt upvote as i dont have enough points to do so